# Applying multiple conditions in SQL?

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I haven't been able to find a similar question for an answer I'm looking for. What is the best way to apply multiple conditions to my query to exclude certain information. `Case` or `Boolean`?

Example code:

```
SELECT test,
testTypeID,
visitType,
submitted
FROM vReport
WHERE (vReport.submitted = 0 OR vReport.submitted IS NULL)
AND vReport.test IN ('Test 1','Test 2','Test 3')
```

How do I best code for it to return all the tests 1, 2, and 3 while excluding rows for certain visit types (i.e. exclude row ONLY if it is `Test 3` AND it is visit `Week 26` AND a certain `testTypeID`)?

Comment: what you are doing looks correct

Answer (score 0):

<>Not sure what your column names and datatypes are for visitWeek (assuming this is an INT) and testTypeID and what values you want to filter by but here is the logic for it:

```
SELECT test,
testTypeID,
visitType,
submitted
FROM vReport
WHERE (vReport.submitted = 0 OR vReport.submitted IS NULL)
AND vReport.test IN ('Test 1','Test 2','Test 3') 
AND (vReport.test NOT IN ('Test 3') AND vReport.testTypeID NOT IN (some value) AND vReport.visitWeek <> 26)
```

Comment: AND `vReport.visitWeek <> 26`

Comment: I'm essentially trying to have a row not appear when two conditions are true. When 'test = 'Test 1'' and 'visitType = 'Week 26'', then testTypeID cannot equal 'ABC123'.

Answer (score 0):

If you can define your exclusions homogeneously, you can store them in another table. Something like:

**ExcludedTest**

```
excludedTestId
test
visitType
testTypeId
```

and your query can be done like this:

```
SELECT test,
testTypeID,
visitType,
submitted
FROM vReport VR
WHERE (vReport.submitted = 0 OR vReport.submitted IS NULL)
   AND vReport.test IN ('Test 1','Test 2','Test 3')
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ExcludedTest ET 
                    WHERE ET.testTypeID = VR.testTypeID 
                       AND ET.visitType = VR.visitType
                       AND ET.test = VR.test)
```

Also, you should have a better performance if you exclude that OR. One way to do this is to keep `submitted` as `NOT NULL` with `DEFAULT(0)` => `vReport.submitted = 0` condition is enough.